# Get actual Query() value instead of parsed one

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, prisma

I have a method in the controller to retrieve multiple records along with pagination and filtering.

```
  @Get()
  findAll(
        @Query('skip') skip: string,
        @Query('take') take: string,
        @Query('sortBy') sortBy: string,
        @Query('content') content: string,
        @Query('isCorrect') isCorrect?: boolean | null,
  ) {
    console.log(isCorrect, typeof isCorrect); // <-- param isCorrect skipped = false, boolean
    const filters: AnswerFilters = { content, isCorrect };
    return this.answersService.offsetPaginate(Number(skip), Number(take), sortBy, filters);
  }
```

I have a problem with `@Query('isCorrect') isCorrect?: boolean | null`. If I send `true` or `false` via Postman, this value actually shows up and that is correct. However, if I skip sending this param, I get `false` instead of `null` which is incorrect.
I need to read this `null` to later skip filtering by this field.

Is it possible to prevent this parsing to boolean somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think NestJS parses query parameters at all. They should always be strings.

Which means I think you want:

```
@Query('isCorrect') isCorrectParam?: string,
```

Followed by:

```
let isCorrect = null
if (isCorrectParam === 'true') isCorrect = true
if (isCorrectParam === 'false') isCorrect = false

const filters: AnswerFilters = { content, isCorrect: isCorrect === 'true' };
```

This will ensure that when pass `?isCorrect=true` you convert that to a boolean `true`, if you pass `?isCorrect=false` you get boolean `false`, and if you omit the param or pass any other value, you get `null`.